# How to fix this? i cant start my first app

Tags: android-studio, flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
  Process command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe -Xmx1536M -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\Thashreef.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all\9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb\gradle-5.6.2\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.2.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 5.6.2

  ### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: did you Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: How do i do that? im new to android studio can you tell me step by step ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your Java environment is causing the incompatibility of Android studio, please open the project settings in your AS and set its Java environment to the Jdk that comes with AS